# How to keep track of an array change in Vue.js when the index is a dynamic value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am building an app using Node.js and Vue.
My DATA for the component is the following:

```
data() {
    return {
        campaign: {
          buses: [],
          weeks: [
            {
              oneWayBuses: [],
              returnBuses: []
            }
          ]
        },
        busesMap: {
          // id is the bus ID. Value is the index in the campaign.buses array.
        },
    };
  },
```

I fill the buses and weeks array in MOUNTED section in two separate methods after getting the data from the server:

```
   responseForWeeks => {
      responseForWeeks.forEach(
        week => this.campaign.weeks.push(week);
      )
   }

   responseForBuses => {
      responseForBuses.forEach(
         bus => this.campaign.buses.push(bus);
         // Here I also fill the busesMap to link each week to its bus index in the array of buses
         this.busesMap[bus.id] = this.campaign.buses.length - 1;
      )
   }
```

So the idea is that my busesMap looks like busesId keys and index values:

```
   busesMap = {
      'k3jbjdlkk': 0,
      'xjkxh834b': 1,
      'hkf37sndd': 2

   }
```

However, when I try to iterate over weeks, v-if does not update so no bus info is shown:

```
   <ul>
      <li 
         v-for="(busId, index) in week.oneWayBuses"
         :key="index"
         :item="busId"
      >
         <span v-if="campaign.buses[busesMap.busId]">
            <strong>{{ campaign.buses[busesMap.busId].busLabel }}</strong>
             leaves on the
            <span>{{ campaign.buses[busesMap.busId].oneWayDepartureDate.toDate() | formatDate }}</span>
         </span>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

On the other side, if I shorten the `v-if` condition to `campaign.buses`, then I get into the condition but `campaign.buses[busesMap.busId]` is still undefined, so I get an ERROR trying to display `busLabel` and `oneWayDepartureDate`

I've read vue in [depth documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html), but couldn't come up with a resolution.
Any gotchas you can find out?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `v-for="(busId, index) in campaigns.weeks.oneWayBuses"`?

Comment: Good point, but I have another v-for="(week, index) in campaign.weeks" above. That's why in the next iteration I just use v-for="(busId, index) in week.oneWayBuses".

Comment: without seeing anything that is `week` it's hard to say

Comment: Week has many keys but I believe the only important here are `oneWayBuses[]` and `returnBuses[]`. Will try to add more info on the description.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
async mounted(){
  await responseForWeeks
  await responseForBuses
responseForWeeks => {
      responseForWeeks.forEach(
        week => this.campaign.weeks.push(week);
      )
   }
// this is partial since it is what you provided
   responseForBuses => {
      responseForBuses.forEach(
         bus => this.campaign.buses.push(bus);
         // Here I also fill the busesMap to link each week to its bus index in the array of buses
         this.busesMap[bus.id] = this.campaign.buses.length - 1;
      )
   }
   }
```

Basically you want to make sure that before your component loads your data is in place. You can also create computed properties which will force re rendering if dependencies are changed and they are in the dom.

Comment: I've added those features in the code. When I check in the VueDevtools, values of `campaign.buses`, `campaign.weeks` and `busesMap` are all up-to-date as expected. So to me it looks like there's an issue on the HTML `v-for`/ `v-if`formulas. Thanks anyway Michael!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was indeed in the HTML.
When trying to access the object keys, better use `[]` intead of a dot `.`

Final HTML result would be as follows:

```
<ul>
   <li 
      v-for="(busId, index) in week.oneWayBuses"
      :key="index"
      :item="busId"
   >
       <span v-if="campaign.buses[[busesMap[busId]]]">
          <strong>{{ campaign.buses[busesMap[busId]].busLabel }}</strong>
          leaves on the 
          <span>{{ campaign.buses[busesMap[busId]].oneWayDepartureDate.toDate() | formatDate }}</span>
       </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What was happening is that previously `campaign.buses[busesMap.busId]` did not exist, thus not rendering anything. Solved to `campaign.buses[busesMap[busId]]`. Also used claudators for the displayed moustache sintach.

Hope it helps someone else messing with **Objects**!